# Find average value of lines which have duplicated variable

Tags: r

Input:

How do I take the average of the lines which are duplicated in `Var1`.

```
    Var1            Var2            Var3    value   
1   hsa-let-7a-5p   hsa-let-7a-1    124G    15.1096198266
2   hsa-let-7a-5p   hsa-let-7a-2    124G    15.1100852974
3   hsa-let-7a-5p   hsa-let-7a-3    124G    15.1092706389
24  hsa-miR-125b-5p hsa-mir-125b-1  124G    7.785156036
25  hsa-miR-125b-5p hsa-mir-125b-2  124G    7.785156036
```

Output:

```
    Var1                Var3    value   
    hsa-let-7a-5p       124G    "Average of hsa-let-7a in Var2 in input"
    hsa-miR-125b-5p     124G    "Average of hsa-mir-125b in Var2 in input"
```

Comment: The question has been answered several time on SO. Try: `aggregate(df$value, by=list(df$Var1), mean)`. There also lots of solution using `data.table`, `dplyr` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would work with the `plyr` package here.

```
require(plyr)    
df2 <- ddply(df,.(Var1,Var3),summarize, Avg=mean(value))
```

Within the brackets you state all the variables you want to keep and you can calculate the mean, sd or whatever you want of the other columns. However with large datasets plyr sometimes gets a bit slow.

The `dplyr` package is suppose to preform better but I don't really have any experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what value to use for `Var3` in the new summarised form, so I will assume just the first `Var3` (doesn't matter for your current sample where all are the same).

```
require(dplyr)
newdf <- df %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>%
  summarize(Var3=first(Var3),
            value=mean(value))
```

Output

```
> newdf
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

             Var1 Var3     value
1   hsa-let-7a-5p 124G 15.109659
2 hsa-miR-125b-5p 124G  7.785156
```

Comment: instead of giving an answer to a question raised 100 times, please consider indicating the OP he should search before and provide the appropriate link to avoid a 101 topic ...

Comment: noted, it just wast faster for me to answer than to search for the duplicate... I guess I can just ignore the question